# Generators of group of units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is distinct from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501378/units-of-mathbbz-sqrt2) since it is about generating the group of units rather than proving that the coefficients of a unit $a+bh$ are coprime.

**How do you classify the units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$? What are the generators of its group of units?**

I have seen rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-D}]$ before, which are geometrically two-dimensional and make nice lattices that are stretched out vertically.

Multiplication by a complex number is a scaled rotation, so it's easy to see why we don't get units outside $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ in the $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-D}]$ case.

Let $h = \sqrt{2}$.

I was looking at $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and I soon found the unit-pair $(1+h)(1-h) = -1$.

##### Theorem 51: every unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ has a conjugate pair that is also a unit.

Every unit must be paired like this. Suppose $a+bh$ is a unit, then $(a+bh)(c+dh) = 1 = (ac+2bd) + (ad+bc)h$. This means that $(a-bh)$ is also a unit since $(a-bh)(c-dh) = (ac+2bd) - (ad+bc)h = 1$, since $(ad+bc)h$ must be zero.

Thus $(a+bh)(c+dh)(a-bh)(c-dh) = 1$, thus every factor in the product on the LHS is a unit.

**End of proof of Theorem 51**.

I found some more conjugate pairs $(3+2h)(3-2h) = 1$ and $(7+5h)(7-5h) = -1$ and a product of these two solutions $(41+29h)(41-29h) = -1$.

Finding *one* simple solution with nontrivial $h$-part is enough to give me infinitely many distinct solutions just by taking powers of that simple solution.

In fact, all the examples I've found so far are powers of $(1+h)$.

- $(1+h)$
- $(3+2h) = (1+h)(1+h)$
- $(7+5h) = (1+h)^3$

This makes me wonder how you generate the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: See Keith Conrad's excellent notes on Dirichlet's Unit Theorem: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ (scroll down the the "Algebraic Number Theory" section; the link is in the fourth row, fourth column).

Comment: Prove that $\sqrt2+1$ is a fundamental unit, that is the smallest element of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]^\times\subset \Bbb{R}^*$ which is $> 1$. It implies easily that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]^\times=\pm (\sqrt2+1)^\Bbb{Z}$.